# MySQL multiple tables of the same name in the same database

Tags: mysql

I have a database, and a set of tables. The scenario is that, two different departments use the exact same table structure and the server code/frontend, but the data for the departments is completely different.

The best thing would be to have two different databases, with the exact structure and different data.

However, if I would try to implement this in just 1 database, would it be possible? I cannot change the table names, as it would require changing the entire code which queries the tables. Is there any way to create sub-folders/directories in a single database?

I searched, and there probably isn't. But maybe there is a workaround someone can suggest?

Comment: no, you cannot create sub-databases, use separate databases

Answer (score 1):

Read about [Identifier Qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html). You can have tables of the same name only if they are in separate databases, and you use the database name as a qualifier.

```
SELECT * FROM db1.sametablename;
SELECT * FROM db2.sametablename;
```

You can join tables across databases in the same query:

```
SELECT * FROM db1.sametablename JOIN db2.sametablename;
```

You can even declare foreign key constraints across databases:

```
ALTER TABLE db1.sametablename ADD FOREIGN KEY (col1) 
  REFERENCES db2.sametablename (col1);
```

Databases are basically a namespace for tables and other objects.

Comment: I agree with this answer. I'm not a fan of cross-database joins or references, though; they can make scalability harder in the long-term. Suppose, for example, you determine that one database needs to be hosted on another server because the load has gotten too high. Now you have cross-server joins and references, which are generally very slow. Not saying they are always bad, just something to watch out for.

Comment: @Jason, thanks, I agree with your caveats. Creating connections between your databases mean you can't separate them. As with so many other examples, coupling should be avoided where possible. I'm just pointing out how databases are simply like namespaces in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the Mysql Server and restart it again, This must solve the issue.
**Windows**

> `mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown`

**Linux**

> `/etc/init.d/mysqld stop` or `service mysqld stop` or `service mysql stop`